# Only allow changes through CloudFront staging dist using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

I want to prevent all AWS IAM users, including admins, from making direct changes to specific CloudFront distributions. This means that in order to make changes, they will have to create a staging distribution and promote it.

I attempted to use the following deny policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::***:distribution/***"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, it appears that when creating a staging distribution, the section which attempts to create the weighted traffic requires `UpdateDistribution` permissions to the primary distribution.

This means that the policy also prevents the creation of a staging distribution.

I tried to break down the events via CloudTrail but couldn't find a way to only allow changes to the primary dist if the request was originated/is related to its kindred staging dist.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behaviour where IAM users can make changes to a CloudFront distribution only through a staging distribution, you can use a combination of IAM policies and AWS CloudFormation with a custom resource. The idea is to allow users to have permission to create/update the staging distribution, and then use a custom resource in CloudFormation to handle the promotion of the staging distribution to the primary distribution.

1. **IAM Policies:**

   Create a policy that allows users to create/update the staging distribution but denies direct updates to the primary distribution.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::YourAccountID:distribution/YourPrimaryDistributionID"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. **AWS CloudFormation with Custom Resource:**

   Use CloudFormation to manage the lifecycle of your CloudFront distributions. Create a CloudFormation template with a custom resource that handles the promotion from staging to primary. The custom resource can be implemented using a Lambda function that has the necessary permissions to perform CloudFront operations.

Here is a simplified example CloudFormation template:

```
Resources:
  StagingDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      # Define your staging distribution properties here

  PromotionFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: promotion.handler
      Role: !GetAtt PromotionFunctionRole.Arn
      FunctionName: PromotionFunction
      Runtime: python3.8
      Code:
        S3Bucket: YourLambdaCodeBucket
        S3Key: path/to/your/promotion-function.zip

  PromotionFunctionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "PromotionFunctionPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "cloudfront:GetDistribution"
                  - "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
                Resource: "*"

  PromotionCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::Promotion
    DependsOn: StagingDistribution
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt PromotionFunction.Arn
      StagingDistributionId: !Ref StagingDistribution
      PrimaryDistributionId: YourPrimaryDistributionId
```

This approach allows you to control and audit changes to your CloudFront distributions through CloudFormation, and IAM policies ensure that users cannot directly update the primary distribution.

Comment: This is clearly a GPT4 response which I already received and is incorrect